# Posting to Friends wall using Facebook C# Sdk

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm designing a WP7.1 App that publishes to other user's wall, using **Facebook C# Sdk**, without user interaction (i.e. in Background).
I searched for methods and discovered that a *POST* would do the things.
However, [Facebook Roadmap Page](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/) and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/) Blog Post, mentions that the ability to post to other user's wall by **Graph API** has been removed and instead **Feeds Dialog** must be used.
My question is:
  - Is this change going to affect the above POST Method.
  - If Yes, then, is there a workaround to POST on other user's wall *without* User Interaction ( i.e. IN Background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now to post on friends wall, either you must use feed dialog, that will prompt user.
but if you don't want to prompt user then you can post on your user wall with a tag to user's friend, assuming friend approve the tag it'll show up on tagged friends wall.